# do i need to install gazebo_ros_pkgs

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Q1: do i need to install gazebo_ros_pkgs in indigo? because the gazebo(gazebo2 ) should be integrated in ROS.

Q2: I hear ROS Hydro supported Gazebo simulation environment better than Indigo, is that true?

Thanks,all.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203737/do-i-need-to-install-gazebo_ros_pkgs/) by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2015-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes....ros Indigo full install will install Gazebo and I have no issues with Gazebo under Indigo. But I do not push it very hard.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2015-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on 2015-02-24**:
Error [gazebo.cc:220] Waited 11 seconds for namespaces. Giving up.
I found a error when i first run Gazebo in terminal install gazebo_ros_pkgs , is that ok?